# NodeJS: upload file using multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am trying to upload a file and without saving it to disk, read the stream. The code I've written is:

```
var storageOriginal = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage(), limits: { fileSize: 1000 * 1000 * 12 } });

var uploadOriginal = multer({ storage: storageOriginal }).array("uploadedFile", 1);

exports.UploadFile = function(req, res, next){
uploadOriginal(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ "message": "Error in reading file stream!"}));
        else {
            var _originalStream = req.files[0].Buffer;//Want to read buffer here. Getting "req.files[0] is undefined"
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is I am not able to read the incoming file. "req.files[0] is undefined". I am using express and the request is "multipart/form-data"

Does anyone know what is wrong with the above code or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Which version of `multer` you are using out there?

Comment: did you already inspect the req.file object?

Comment: @DavidR The version I am using is 1.3.0

Comment: @Roman Yes, all the other fields are OK

Comment: if you create your formData object like: formData.append('file', file); you should be able to retrieve the file in multer by const files = req.files['file'];

Comment: @Roman I don't have control over client. I am creating Restful API.

Comment: did you set multer as middleware in the app.js or in the controller? it should be defined in the app.